# How to send SIP message using Python sockets

Tags: python, sip, invite

I need to send SIP message using Python sockets, I've made that client sends something to server but I'm not able to make that client sends a SIP message INVITE to server

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

R_IP = '192.168.2.1'
R_PORT = 5060 

message = 'INVITE sip:user1110000000350@.com SIP/2.0 To: <sip:user4110000000350@whatever.com>\x0d\x0aFrom: sip:user9990000000000@rider.com;tag=R400_BAD_REQUEST;taag=4488.1908442942.0\x0d\x0aP-Served-User: sip:user4110000000350@whatever.com\x0d\x0aCall-ID: 00000000-00001188-71C0873E-0@10.44.40.47\x0d\x0aCSeq: 1 INVITE\x0d\x0aContact: sip:user9990000000000@rider.com\x0d\x0aMax-Forwards: 70\x0d\x0aVia: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.44.40.47;branch=z9hG4bK1908442942.4488.0\x0d\x0aContent-Length: 10\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0aRandomText'

def sendPacket():
   proto = socket.getprotobyname('tcp')                         
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)#, proto) 

   try:
       s.connect((R_IP , R_PORT)) 
       s.sendall(message)                                       
   except socket.error:
       pass
   finally:
       s.close()

sendPacket()
```

Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I know, maybe it will help someone.

Proper format SIP message is as follows:

```
INVITE sip:user11@whatever SIP/2.0
To: <to>
Call-ID: <call_id>
<empty line>
body
```

So,

```
message = 'INVITE sip:user1110000000350@whatever.com SIP/2.0\r\nTo: <sip:user4110000000350@whatever.com>\r\nFroma: sip:user9990000000000@rider.com;tag=R400_BAD_REQUEST;taag=4488.1908442942.0\r\nP-Served-User: sip:user4110000000350@whatever.com\r\nCall-ID: 00000000-00001188-71C0873E-0@10.44.40.47\r\nCSeq: 1 INVITE\r\nContact: sip:user9990000000000@rider.com\r\nMax-Forwards: 70\r\nVia: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.44.40.47;branch=z9hG4bK1908442942.4488.0\r\nContent-Length: 10\r\n\r\nRandomText'
```

`\r\n` is very important without empty spaces

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261):

1. Each header must start with a newline and there must be no whitespaces before header name.
2. Minimal SIP request must contain `To`, `From`, `CSeq`, `Call-ID`, `Max-Forwards` and `Via` headers.

This means that you correctly added newline before `To` header, but your answer also incorrectly contains `Froma` header instead of `From`. Also, header `P-Served-User` is generally unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @Andriy, `Froma` is probably a mistake, a typo mistake. And then I had to send a message with `P-Served-User` and i probaby hadn't cut it from the code.